# BigQuery - unable to run select * from saved view, which runs successfully on its own

Tags: google-bigquery

I currently have a series of views in BigQuery which "feed" into each other, much like the image attached.  In the picture, the green circles represent created views, and the blue represent already created tables, which are updated daily by incoming data.

I am able to successfully run the script that makes up V8 (SELECT * FROM V6 JOIN V7 ON v6.attribute = V7.attribute, but I get a "**Error: Resources exceeded during query execution**." error when I run a SELECT * FROM V8.  Shouldn't this be the same query? What would cause SELECT * FROM V6 JOIN V7... to succeed and SELECT * FORM V8 to fail?

Also, When running my last view (SELECT * FROM FINAL_RESULTS), I receive the same "exceeded resources" error as before, and I am guessing this is because of the error in V8.

I have already taken the steps to use JOIN EACH and GROUP EACH BY in V6, V7, V8, and the FINAL_RESULTS, but I still get the same error.

I know the multiple views seem unnecessary, but they are used for many reasons outside of what I am trying to accomplish, and since the data they reference in the tables is always being updated, they need to be dynamic.

[In the picture, the green circles represent created views, and the blue represent already created tables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYAZm.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just in case you aren't aware of it already, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#resourcesExceeded offers some advice on troubleshooting issues like this.

Comment: The just announced EXPLAIN functionality might help you troubleshoot this issue too. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation.

Comment: I don't have the EXPLAIN button in my UI. Is it fully rolled out yet?

Answer (score 2):

I think you hit nested views limitation. I think it was 8

confirmed - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data?hl=en#views
BigQuery supports up to eight levels of nested views

Comment: Exceeding the maximum number of nested views generates a "Too many nested views or possible circular reference of views referenced in query." error. I suspect OP is hitting a legitimate resources exceeded error. (They could confirm by adding a V9 view to see if that changes the error message.)

Comment: Also note that the view limit is a nested depth limit, not an overall maximum number of views referenced in the query. In the picture OP included, the maximum view depth is 5.

Comment: good point. i noticed this when answered, but still thought would be great to mention netsed view related limit